# How should I write code if a params[:id] doesn't exist in the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a show action in a controller and want to branch if no id received from `params[:id]` exists in my database.

My app is still being created. I've tried conditional branching and exception handling. However, they didn't work as expected.

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  #...

  def show
    begin
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    rescue
      render root
    end
  end

  #...

end
```

I expect to be redirect to the root if any error occurs.

The above code returns the record if it is found successfully. However, an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show` occurs if no record is found.

How should I write code for this error?

Comment: Note from the answers that they all use find_by instead of find, even though you're just checking for id. It's because find_by returns nil if no entry is found. find throws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I write code for this error?

The short answer is "you shouldn't".

Exceptions should, IMO, be exceptional. It sounds like you might expect this circumstance, so I suggest you write code that handles the scenario without raising an exception.

If you really think you'll have circumstances where the `Article` record does not exist for the given `params[:id]` (seems a little odd, but I guess it's possible), then I would suggest that you use `.find_by` instead of `.find`:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  #...

  def show
    if @article = Article.find_by(id: params[:id])
      # do something with the article 
    else
      render root
    end
  end

  #...

end
```

It seems like to you might want to do a `redirect` instead of a `render`:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  #...

  def show
    if @article = Article.find_by(id: params[:id])
      # do something with the article 
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  #...

end
```

But, maybe not...

Also, rescuing everything like this:

```
def show
  begin
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  rescue
    render root
  end
end
```

...is generally viewed as code smell. There are a [lot of articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+don%27t+rescue) on the interwebs about why.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the exception from `ArticlesController` but I advise put the code at 
`ApplicationController` like this:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
   redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, alert: t("resource_not_found")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can code like this:

```
 def show
    @article = Article.find_by(id: params[:id])
    unless @article.present?
      flash[:error] = "Not Found."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Comment: Even after asking this question, I was looking for an answer on the internet. For now, it works as expected with `Article.exists?(params[:id])`. However, your answer is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

why write so much code, while you can achieve with two lines only.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @article = Article.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_path unless @article.present?
  end 
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code should be written like this:

```
 def show
    begin
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    rescue
      redirect_to root_path
    end
 end
```